# Implementing an interface then calling the Initialize() function

Tags: c#, vb.net

this wont be easy to explain clearly but here goes...

i have something that works fine in VB but not in C#.

i have 2 classes, each class implements a different interface. each interface exposes an Initialize() function that should get called automatically when the plugin loads. since each class has an Initialize() function, i can watch both functions get called in the log. this works fine in VB.

when i do this same thing in C#, only the Initialize() in the first class gets called. anyone have a clue as to why this might be happening?

vb code:

```
Public Class class1
    Implements Interface1

    Public Sub Initialize() Implements Interface1.Initialize
        msgbox("initialize from class1")
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class class2
    Implements Interface2

    Public Sub Initialize() Implements Interface2.Initialize
        msgbox("initialize from class2")
    End Sub
End Class
```

C# code:

```
public class class1 : interface1
{
    public void Initialize()
    {
        messagebox.show("initialize from class1");
    }
}

public class class2 : interface2
{
    public void Initialize()
    {
        messagebox.show("initialize from class2");
    }
}
```

as you can see the code is identical in both languages. why does it work in VB and not in C#?

Comment: Can you share the code that is calling the initialize functions?

Comment: unfortunately i dont have access to the calling code. the developer just supplies the interface for me to use. if you have an idea of some kind i can pass it on for them to look at.

Comment: Then your second class is not loaded by the library/calling code. Check your configuration, have you somehow let the calling code know about the existance of your `class2` class?

Comment: @Zasz why would it work in VB then? the calling code calls the interface method Initialize(). in C# only once class's Initialize is being called. in VB both are called.

Comment: When you tried, were the VB class and C# class in different projects?, If yes then look for difference in the config of these 2. If no, let us know what library u are consuming or what tool or API the calling code is.

Comment: I have a single VB solution/project and a single C# solution/project. they are completely separate.

Comment: Just thinking out loud.. could be a cassing problem in c#???

Comment: I think @gbianchi is correct - C# is case-sensitive, VB.NET isn't. initialize is not the same as Initialize.

Comment: It is Initialize() in both interfaces... forgive me example

Comment: thinking out loud again, what happens if your class2 implements interface1.. and what about the opposite.. you see two calls and no calls?

Comment: What happens when you open your C# and VB.NET DLLs in a decompiler like dotPeek? Do you see any differences between the decompiled class in the C# assembly vs. the decompiled class in the VB.NET assembly?

Comment: This question is a münchausen by proxy problem, and is unsolvable with the current information. Basically, your question is like this: My left foot seems to get hurt periodically, and I can pick out a number of pellets from it every time. Why is that? The problem is that you've left out that you have a shotgun wired to shoot whenever anyone enters your home. Let me rephrase that. You've talked about the classes that exhibit the problems, but you've showed none of the code that *involves* the classes. As such, we cannot tell why one class works and the other doesn't.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen thanks for your brilliant observations. Of course if you bothered to read the rest of the page you would know that I posted all I could. The calling code is something I do not have access to. I only have an interface that the dev provides. So I posted all that I could hoping that someone might pick up on something obvious that I missed like a syntax problem. Pretty much the very point of this site, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your help! It turns out the problem was in the calling code. Long story short, each plugin has a command ID as part of the interface. In this case both have ID 1000. When the calling code loops through plugins to load, if it sees a duplicate ID it skips that plugin. My problem was that I was loading other plugins at the same time with the same ID. You all helped find a bug in the calling code (which is pretty well-known software) so thank you!

Comment: **You all helped find a bug in the calling code (which is pretty well-known software) so thank you!** This isn't a bug.  Of course one could argue that the software loading the extension should assign it a identification number.

Comment: @Ramhound, No, it's a bug in the software (confirmed). Loading plugins shouldn't fail when a previous plugin has already been loaded that implements a particular command ID. Why? Because multiple plugins should be able to run the command defined by that ID. Get it now?

Answer (score 0):

Is the constructor of both classes called? Or is only the fist class initialized? 
Please try adding a (static) constructor to check which classes are initialzed.

Static Constructor for one Class:

```
public class class2 : interface2
{
    static class2(){
        messagebox.show("Static Constructor from class2");
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        messagebox.show("initialize from class2");
    }
}
```

Comment: i have to assume theyre both called because again, this works fine in VB.... right? or am i missing something? where would you have me put the static constructor? which class?

Comment: I would try a static constructor in both classes, just to be sure :-)
maybe you have a problem with your c# assembly and only one class can be found.
Are those two classes in the same assembly?
Are they the production code or is it a shorten form?
If I guess right the classes are called by reflection, so its an AddIn model or?

Comment: if you give me an example of a static constructor ill try :) and yes, for each project the classes are both in the same assembly. the classes are not being called by reflection. the projects are DLLs that get loaded by another application as a plugin.